# visual studio breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a question about setting breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

In the struct below, I have an `Update()` function which, depending on certain conditions, updates the value of it's member `i`:

```
struct A
{
    A(int i) : i(i) {}

    void Update()
    {
        //Update i if some condition is met...
        if(something)
            i += 2;
    }

    int i;
};

int main()
{
    A a(2);

    //Update is usually called periodically...
    a.Update();

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to set a breakpoint to be hit when `i` equals 4. The only way I know how to do this is to change the Update() function like so:

```
void Update()
{
        //Update i if some condition is met...
        if(something)
            i += 2;

        if(i == 4)
            int dummy = 1;
}
```

Now I can set a breakpoint on the line:

```
int dummy = 1;
```

And I will hit a breakpoint when `i` equals `4`. Is there a cleaner or easier way to set a breakpoint in a situation like this? How do I do it without adding in the dummy code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the usual way with your mouse.  This puts a big red dot in the left margin of your code.  Now right-click on the big red dot with your mouse.  You will see a list of ways you can change your breakpoint.  Choose "Condition...".  Then you can enter `i==4` into the condition box.  You'll have a breakpoint that breaks at that point when `i` is 4.

Comment: Oops, I am used to setting breakpoint by hitting F9 and didn't realize you could set more options. Thanks :)